# Call method in generic object

Tags: c#, generics

Is there some way that this can work?

```
class A
{
    public virtual string Greet() { return "Hello"; }
}
class B : A
{
    public override string Greet() { return "Hola"; }
}
class C : A
{
    public override string Greet() { return "Привет"; }
}
class Greeting<T>
{
    List<T> list;
    public Greeting(List<T> list)
    {
        this.list = new List<T>();
        this.list.AddRange(list);
    }
    public void Show()
    {
        foreach (T el in list)
            el.Greet(); // 'T' does not contain a definition for 'Greet'
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<A> list = new List<A>() { new A(), new B(), new C() };
        Greeting<A> g = new Greeting<A>(list);
        g.Show();
    }
}
```

I know that in this case I should write `List<Shop> list`(in Greeting class) and don't use generic class...but I need this implementation to work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add a [constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) on `T`, without it, the compiler has no way of knowing you will only pass objects which derive from `A` and the method isn't available:

```
class Greeting<T> where T : A
{
   List<T> list;
   public Greeting(List<T> list)
   {
       this.list = new List<T>();
       this.list.AddRange(list);
   }
   public void Show()
   {
      foreach (T el in list)
         el.Greet(); // 'T' does not contain a definition for 'Greet'
   }
}
```